# Dynamically securing Spring Rest endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-security

Actually my code look like that:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/xxxx", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<> method(@RequestBody RequestClass request) {

}
```

As you can see the allowed authorities are hard-coded in java code.
Is there a way to override the behaviour of `PreAuthorize` or to load the proper endpoint configuration at startup from an external source(database or configuration file)?

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically change the allowed authorities?

Comment: @Sandrogo because I prefer to have all the configuration in a single point instead of having it spread in java files

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might give something like this a try (might need some tweaking) but it's ugly and I would not do it myself...

1. Setup your method to role mappings in your configuration. For example:

```
permissions.method1: admin
permissions.method2: admin
permissions.method3: user
```

2. Then use an @ConfigurationProperties class to load in your map into a Map.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("")
public class SecurityMappingProperties {

    private final Map<String, String> permissions = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

}
```

3. Then setup a service to handle the lookup.

```
@Service
public class MethodPermissionService {

  @Autowired
  private SecurityMappingProperties mappingProperties;

  //lookup the mapped role and see if you user has it..
  public Boolean lookupPermissionForMethod(String method){
     return doesUserHaveRole(mappingProperties.get(method));
  }

  private Boolean doesUserHaveRole(String role){
     //implement whatever logic you want to look up the requesting user's role...
  }

}
```

4. Then in your controllers, invoke the methodPermissionService and pass in the method name, like so...

```
@PreAuthorize("@methodPermissionService('method1')")
```

This, of course, would require you to have **every** secured method in **all** of your controllers to have an @Preauthorize with the matching method name as the argument to the methodPermissionService('xxx').

Since we are already in this rabbit hole, if you really wanted to, you could also just have a single place to declare all of them in some sort of MethodRoleHolder class where you can make them static Strings like the following:

```
 public static final String METHOD1_SECURITY = "@methodPermissionService('method1')";

 public static final String METHOD2_SECURITY = "@methodPermissionService('method2')";
```

then use them in your controllers...

```
@PreAuthorize(MethodRoleHolder.METHOD1_SECURITY)
```

Upfront caveat: I haven't actually tried this myself exactly as I laid out here but I have implemented a security scheme similar to this, just without the dynamic role mapping look up part.